# How to assign a value in a list to an object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following statesments:

```
A = "s"
B = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want to get the object "A" when I am printing B[2], e.g: `print(B[2])`, and the answer will give me "A" with a reference to the value of A..

How can I do it in python?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thank you all.

The same question in another manner:

I have seen this in the forum:

```
>>>foo = 'a string'
>>>id(foo) 
4565302640
>>> bar = 'a different string'
>>> id(bar)
4565321816
>>> bar = foo
>>> id(bar) == id(foo)
True
>>> id(bar)
4565302640
```

But if I have:

```
>>> foo = "a string"
>>> id(foo)
36591240
>>> bar = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> id(bar)
39186840
>>> bar[2] = foo
>>> id(bar) == id(foo)
Flase
```

How can I assign a value in a list to match a different obect?

Comment: is there a reason you can't put `A` in the list? `B = ["1", "2", A]`

Comment: In code that doesn't use functions or classes, you're pretty much limited to what Andrew said.

Comment: I can not put A in the list, becuase I want A will stay an object of its own, and B will be another one. How can I do match "3" with A by using functions or classes?

Comment: Putting `A` in the list does not in any way prevent `A` from being "an object of its own".

Answer (score 2):

What you need to have is `id(bar[2]) == id(foo)`. This will return True.

Generally lists are mutable so you can assign whatever value you want particular list element to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you do this, but defining a new `list` class could help:

```
class NewList(list):
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self._mapping = mapping
        list.__init__(self)
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        item = list.__getitem__(self, key)
        return self._mapping[item]
```

Then, you can use it as a list after you define a mapping showing which item corresponds to which object:

```
A = "s"
mapping = {"3": A}

B = NewList(mapping)
B.extend(["1", "2", "3"])  

print(B[2])
```

Output:

```
s
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR `B[2] = A`

You need to understand that in python string objects are immutable objects,
This mean those objects cannot be changed and they behave different from mutable objects.

So after defining a string, an object is created. but because this object is immutable, If you assign other variable pointing to the same object, when you will change the original variable, you are creating a new object and not changing the object you created.

for mutable objects the assign is just like you will normally do
for example look at this:

```
In [1]: A = ['s']

In [2]: B = ['1','2','3']

In [3]: B[2] = A

In [4]: id(B[2]) == id(A)
Out[4]: True
```

And for your example you can define a new class instead of string

```
In [1]: class MutableString:
   ...:     def __init__(self, value):
   ...:         self.value = value
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return self.value
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return repr(self.value)
   ...:

In [2]: A = MutableString('foo')

In [3]: B = ['1', '2', '3']

In [4]: B[2] = A

In [5]: print(B)
['1', '2', 'foo']

In [6]: A.value = 'bar'

In [7]: print(B)
['1', '2', 'bar']

In [8]: id(B[2]) == id(A)
Out[8]: True
```